# Can someone explain to me how math.sqrt() work in this situtation?

Tags: python, primes

if n is from 5 through 15

```
for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2):
    if n%i == 0:
        return False
return True
```

another question is that the "return True" can it be written like this, if not, how are they different?

```
for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2):
    if n%i == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how it works"? It computes the square root of `n` - it's the only thing it does.

Comment: What is the first question? The second one will fail if `n` is 4, where it will output `True` when `i` is 3.

Comment: BTW, if you're using Python >= 3.8, it would be better to use `math.isqrt(n)` than `int(math.sqrt(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

For your first code block, `range(3, int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2)` means that the `for` loop will start at the number 3, and contain every other number until `int(math.sqrt(n))+1`. `math.sqrt(n)` is just the square root of `n`. `int()` is converting that number to an integer, meaning anything after its decimal point is truncated. `if n%i == 0:` is checking if `n` divided by `i` contains no remainder, meaning `n` is divisible by `i`.

The difference in return statements between your first and second code block is that the second code block will always return on the very first item, whereas in the first code block, it will return `True` only if `False` wasn't returned for any items.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is for testing whether an odd number `n` is prime. It does this by testing all the odd numbers from 3, to see if any of them divide it evenly.

`math.sqrt(n)` is used because the largest prime factor that could possibly divide evenly into a number is its square root, so there's no point in testing numbers larger than this. There could be other factors larger than this, but they'll be multiples of smaller numbers that were already tested.

The second version is not correct because it returns `True` as soon as it finds a number that doesn't divide evenly into `n`. But there could still be a larger number that does divide into it. For instance, if `n` were `25`, it would return `True` because `3` doesn't divide into it. You need to go through *all* the potential divisors, and only return `True` if none of them divide into it.